# 30amp RV electric Help!

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a 30 amp RV. I had a new breaker put in my breaker box cause it only had one 15amp breaker installed when I got it. I had three room plugs ran in my camper to the other breaker can I put 20 amp breakers in instead? And what amp plug do I need to run both breakers the other breaker was for fridge and ac and water heater everything else is on the other breaker

Comment: Was the wiring done using 14AWG or 12AWG?

Answer (score 1):

Do not replace a 15A breaker with a 20A breaker. Breakers are sized to protect the weakest part of the system and if that is the wiring then using a larger breaker creates a fire risk.

If the original design was planned that none of the loads would be in use at the same time ( a poor plan imho) then a 15A breaker may have been (incorrectly) deemed sufficient.

If you want to split off the circuits then add 15A breakers but check the supply side wiring to make sure that it is sufficiently sized to handle multiple loads.

Answer (score 0):

I can't yet comment on your question, so this answer will not be what you're after...

Solar Mike is right; do not simply replace breakers with larger values! We need to know what you mean by "what amp plug to run both breakers".

Generally, you can put 15-amp outlets on a circuit that is fed thru a 15-amp breaker with 15-amp wire, 20-amp outlets thru 20-amp breaker using 20-amp wire, etc.

But please don't risk a fire by trying to tackle electrical work when you don't understand why you're doing what you're doing, or what you need to not do!